# The inverse function of $x \mapsto 2x^3 + 5 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I calculate the inverse of:

$$ \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}: x \mapsto 2x^3 + 5 $$

as:

$$ \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}: x \mapsto [(x-5)/2]^{1/3} $$

apparently it is not right, but I don't see where the problem is. Input output seems fine, so I do not see why my answer is not right. Anyone has any idea?

Also, $ (-27)^{1/3} $ should be equal to $ -(27)^{1/3} $. But when I enter the former, [this calculator](http://web2.0calc.com/) seems to go berserk, I find that quite weird as well. Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: it works and it has nothing to do with theoretical mathematics

Comment: The calculator output the right answer, -3, for me.  Your inverse function looks good, why do you think it's not right?

Comment: when I enter (-27)^(1/3) it gives me error: not real

Comment: Use the cube root function instead of the $1/3$ power and the calculator will give the correct answer.  I think that the calculator is rounding $1/3$ to a decimal and doesn't compute the power correctly.

Comment: it's the developer's problem nothing for you.

Comment: okay thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Gravity Heh must be a mistake someplace in the programming. if you use $\sqrt[3]{-27}$ it works fine. As does $\sqrt[2]{-27}$ which ends up being the correct complex number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inverse function is correct. Let the original function be $f(x)$ and your proposed inverse function be $g(x)$. You can show algebraically that $f(g(x))=x$ and $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. This shows your answer to be correct. You can also check this with a graphing calculator, program, or web page, by graphing $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ and seeing that both graphs are the line $y=x$.

Many calculators cannot handle $(-27)^{1/3}$ properly. I just checked the calculator that comes with my iPhone 5s and it gives an error. My TI-30X IIS and my TI-Nspire CX both give the correct answer.

Simpler calculators, as well as many computer languages, calculate $(-27)^{1/3}$ by calculating $1/3$ as a floating point number. They then try to calculate $a^b$ as $e^{b\ln a}$ but of course choke when trying to find $\ln(-27)$. This method of calculating powers works fine for positive base and non-integral exponent but fails for negative base and non-integral exponent. (I know this is how some computer languages work since I have examined the source code for powers in multiple languages.)

This is because simpler calculators do not have a fraction type, just a floating point type and perhaps an integer type. They are not smart enough to convert power one-third to a cube root. If it has an integer type it can correctly calculate $(-1)^2$, but even this may not work if it only uses the floating point type.

You can probably solve this by using the cube root function of your calculator, if it has one. My iPhone does have one and it correctly finds $\sqrt[3]{-27}$.

Comment: Itried but I don't have enough rep to vote up sorry:D

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the correct inverse function; the original function takes a number, cubes it, doubles it and adds 5. That means the inverse function will subtract 5, half it and then cube root it, as your inverse does.

According to whom is it not right? Maybe a typo in the solution you've been given?

As for the calculator issue, the only thing I can see that MIGHT be a problem is the possibility of complex roots, but normally you have to use a fairly awkward mode to get to complex numbers! Given though that there is only one real answer to the cube root of -27, it is a bit odd!